# NestJs project does not show the updates with "tsc" command before "npm run start" or "npm run start:dev"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, nestjs

I am new at nestjs.
So for learning purposes i started tutorial. After I update or change my code, I couldn't find any reflections in my results. Please help me with this. I am providing my *tsconfig.json* file and *package.json* here.

**tsconfig.json**

```
  {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "chashi",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^9.0.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "28.1.8",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "28.1.3",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "28.0.8",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "4.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

I have created this project with "`nest new project_name`" command. and each time it is seems like nothing works without tsc command. Thanks

Comment: So...what's the actual issue here? What's happening, and what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: It happened every time after starting a new project. "ctr + s" does not show the updates that is made in nest project. but i have managed to solve it. I am giving my ans here in the comment section thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some findings i have managed to get a solution.
At the beginning I used to open a new module, controller and service with commands like "nest generate module user",  "nest generate controller user/user--flat", "nest g service user". I learnt from a tutorial from Udemy.
Anyways now i managed to solve this problem by only providing command "nest g resource user". And it worked just fine. Though i don't know what was wrong.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

NestJs is compatible with both typescript and JavaScript. to use nestJs with vanilla JavaScript (Plain javascript) we need a babel compiler.

https://docs.nestjs.com/first-steps

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/index.html